# Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"

Tags: safari, localhost

We use Safari to run content manager software on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

We are getting this error:
Safari Can't Connect to the Server. Safari can't open the page "localhost:8080" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost".

I've tried other web browsers with similar errors. Apache is up to date and running: Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Does not seem to me like there is enough information. There are dozens important configuration settings involved, but you give just the server version. Show us some configs. Show us some attempts to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Got a similar issue with angular-cli and Safari on MacOS Sierra (works as expected with chrome).
To make it works, i'm using 127.0.0.1:4200 instead of localhost:4200.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for certain applications (particularly in development) as certain saml authentication redirects may be sent from a service back to "localhost".

Comment: This did not work for me wherein was trying to pass data from web to localhost. 

Still getting 

```
Not allowed to request resource
```

```
Fetch API cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8350/callback/ due to access control checks.
```